# Notifying changes in datatable in android

Tags: android, database, contentobserver

In my android application, there is a service which inserts records into database table A, and I need to do some operation whenever any new record is inserted in the database table A.

How can I continuously observe table A with a ContentObserver? What URI should I give to get notified whenever any change occurs in table A as we do in order to observe CallLogs and Contacts URIs?

Answer (score 2):

You can't "observe a table" with a content provider. Changes in SQLite db cannot trigger any java code.

You can however (and this is what contacts and log providers do) notify everyone interested after each insert.

So:

- either move your inserting into a custom content provider, and let it notify its listeners,
- Or - if you need something lighter - send a simple broadcast intent saying "the data has changed" (and listen to the broadcast).

Answer (score 0):

the same way: create a custom ContentProvider to access your db tables

Comment: ok, thanks for your suggestion. I think i should use broadcasts to send notifications.